# Can I use SVN on a Linux server with Xcode?

Tags: svn, xcode

Can I use SVN on a Linux server with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Using Subversion with Xcode 3 on Mac OS X Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html) document. Figure 3 shows how to configure Xcode to access a SVN repository.